# How to make sure selected item in vuetify combobox is a part of its items options?

Tags: vue.js, combobox, vuetify.js

I want to make sure that the selected item by the user in vue-combobox is part of the choices set.

Answer (score 0):

It is by default unless you have the `hide-selected` prop as per documentation here:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox#api